# issue: javascript switch case don't work with my var

Tags: javascript

I have a issue with js and looking for help...

I'm trying to change the content of a div, but it doesn't work...

My JS:

```
var headerChange = document.getElementById('myId');
var content = '';

function changeDiv(event) {
        switch (event.target.value) {
            case 'A': {
                content = 'Here the new content case A';
                break;
            }
            case 'B': {
                content = "Here the new content case B...";
                break;
            }
        }
    headerChange.innerHTML = content;
}
```

The content (var) don't load the content inside switch case, it return undefined when I click for change the div content... (cus I set the '' value on it... If I change the value, then it change my div content to the value inserted inside it [for examble, if I set var content = 'abc', it loads abc], but I need it working with the values of the switch)

How can I solve it?

thanks.

PS: vannila js.

Answer (score 2):

Hi myId is header element it has no value. It has innerHtml. So you have to use like that.

```js
var headerChange = document.getElementById('myId');
var content = '';
headerChange.addEventListener('click', changeDiv, false);
function changeDiv(event) {
    console.log('event:',event.target.innerHTML)
      switch (event.target.innerHTML) {
          case 'A': {
              content = 'Here the new content case A';
              break;
          }
          case 'B': {
              content = "Here the new content case B...";
              break;
          }
      }
    headerChange.innerHTML = content;
}

function changeDivByButton(action) {
      switch (action) {
          case 'A': {
              content = 'Here the new content case A';
              break;
          }
          case 'B': {
              content = "Here the new content case B...";
              break;
          }
      }
    headerChange.innerHTML = content;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="myId">A</h1>
<button onclick="changeDivByButton('A')">Click me - A</button>
<button onclick="changeDivByButton('B')">Click me - B</button>
```

Comment: This works very well if I need to change the content of the same div, but it is not my case, I need to change the content of a div other than the one that contains the element to be clicked (i.e, i have my buttons A, B, C... on the div 4 and need it to change the content of the div 1 on click). My only problem is that I am not able to assign value to the 'content' variable. Still, thanks for trying to help!

Comment: nice çözüm +1 sir from linkedin

Comment: dude, it works great now! thank you very much!